# Laplace transform of an unusual convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution, dirac-delta, greens-function

I'm trying to solve a (linear, homogeneous) ODE (and find the function f(t)) which includes the convolution
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(G*f)(t) := \int_{-\infty}^tG(t - u)f(u)du + \int_{t}^\infty G(u - t)f(u)du \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here $G(t)$ is the Green's function that satisfies
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2G}{dt^2}(t - u) + G(t - u) = \delta(t - u) \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta distribution. I thought I might try to solve my ODE with a Laplace transform
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) := \int_0^\infty dte^{-st}f(t) \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

(The two-sided Laplace transform is integrated from "$-\infty$" to $\infty$.)

However I'm unsure whether the Laplace transform factorizes my convolution
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\{f*g\}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f\}\mathcal{L}\{g\} \ ?
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Why are you choosing Laplace transform and not Fourier transform?

Comment: Your convolution can be written as an ordinary convolution $(G \circ \operatorname{abs})*f$ where $\operatorname{abs}(t) = |t|.$

Comment: I wanted to avoid the Fourier transform because I want to double check my result.

And thanks for pointing out that my convolution is actually a regular one with absolute value. It solves my issue if I use the two-sided Laplace transform.

Comment: So you have solved it using Fourier transform?